# How to deploy Strapi to Azure via pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, web-deployment, strapi

I am quite new with Strapi, it is my first time to deploy it. 
I have Strapi with MongoDB (Atlas) which work on localhost.
Now I want to deploy to Azure with keeping MongoDb on Atlas.

So my jobs for now are

[image]

1. Authentification
2. npm install
3. PowerShell -> install strapi cli and build my strapi project

[image]

I get en error on the last step.

[image]

My questions are 
"Is it possible to use pipeline on Azure to deploy Strapi?" 
and 
"Can somebody explain my how to do this right?".

I would appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Hi @podeig Did you get a chance to check out below answer? how was it going?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Not yet, working on it. I will give you feedback later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Above error is caused by strapi installation location not being added to the PATH environment variable of the agent machine.

You will have to add strapi installation location to PATH environment variable.

Run `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${env:PATH};installationFolder"` in the script tasks to set PATH environment variable on hosted agent machine. Check here for more information about [setting variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)

On hosted agents the default installation location for yarn is `C:\npm\prefix\bin` rather than `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Yarn\bin`. See this [similar thread](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/issues/43).

So the powershell script looks like this `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${env:PATH};C:\npm\prefix\bin"`. See below screenshot.

[image]

Noted:

The change of PATH environment variable on hosted agent will only take effect in the following tasks. You need to run `strapi build` in a separate powershell task. See below:

Run strapi build in the following powershell task

[image]